# Set parameter value in after parameter form trigger oracle reports

Tags: oracle, plsql, report

I'm trying to set a parameter to a value, based on a user entered parameter in the param form. What is the PL/SQL syntax to set the parameter value in this trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply,

```
:parameter_to_set := <some value>;
```

If "some value" is based on a user-entered parameter, you can refer to that parameter the same way, i.e. preceded by a colon:

```
:parameter_to_set := :user_param; -- for example
```